# Run Javascript within php include

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have my header logo on a php include file. I've created a div on top of the header image and its my intention to have a Javascript slideshow of a few smaller images within the div. When I view the end result it just shows three images all at once. Nothing is moving. I'm learning as I go so any help would be appreciated!

here's my css

```
@charset "utf-8";
img {
    border: 0px solid black;   
}

#banner {
    position: relative;    
}

#slideshow {
   position: absolute;
   top: 18px;
   left: 650px; 

   height: 90px;
   width: 150px;
   padding: 1px;
   background-color: white;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Heres the contents of my php include

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#slideshow').cycle({ fx: 'fade'});
});
</script>
<link href="../style/banner.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div id="banner">
  <a href="/"><img src="../images/header1.png" alt="Header" width="950" height="125" border="0" /></a>
    <div id="slideshow">
    <img src="../images/1.png" width="150" height="90" alt="test1" />
    <img src="../images/2.png" width="150" height="90" alt="test2" />
    <img src="../images/3.png" width="150" height="90" alt="test3" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Gavin a php include doesn't have to have php code

Comment: for start its better to use some jquery plugins and dont work with pure java script [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+image+slider)

Comment: where is your php include?!

Comment: If `cycle` is a jQuery plugin, then you'll need to include it _AFTER_ the jQuery library.

Comment: MMy php include is     <?php include('includes/header.inc.php'); ?>

Comment: @Jay Harris - the title suggests a PHP related question, this is not a PHP related problem.

Comment: @Gavin lol part of the reason for all the dwn votes, but he said within a php include, and the file is assumed to be saved as php. nonetheless still no php code

Comment: Really appreciate the responses and guidance. I'm going to use the link showdev provided and hopefully get it working from that. Again, thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry if the question was worded wrong... I'm learning as I go... The files are all saved as .php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *" When I view the end result it just shows three images all at once. Nothing is moving."*

You must include jQuery **first**, *before* any other jQuery code or plugins...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
```